# javascript, sort array1 based on arry2

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I did the following in javascript:

```
var arr1 =[1,2,3,4];
var arr2 =["ac", "bc", "ad", "e"];
var result = arr1 .sort(function(i, j){return arr2[i].localeCompare(arr2[j])})
document.write(result );
```

my intention was to sort `array1` based on `array2`. I was expecting the result to be `1,3,2,4`, but as it turns out it is `2,1,3,4` can anyone figure out why? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays are 0-indexed, so your sort function starts comparing with the second and all the way through the fifth; ignoring the first element and the fact that there is no 5th element.

Inserting a -1 in the sort function should fix it:

```
arr1.sort(function(i, j){
    return arr2[i-1].localeCompare(arr2[j-1])
});
```

The result is indeed `[1, 3, 2, 4]`

Answer (score 0):

The arguments in the `sort` method are the array items, not their index, so you need to find the index based on the items, assuming the values are unique.

Basic example will be:

```
var result = arr1.sort(function(i, j) {
    return arr2[Find(arr1, i)].localeCompare(arr2[Find(arr1, j)]);
});
```

Where the `Find` function can be:

```
function Find(arr, key) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        if (arr[i] == key)
            return i;
    return -1;
}
```

Test case: http://jsfiddle.net/tqQDJ/

Comment: Thanks for answering, appreciate it.