# my solution to 2-sum is slow?

Tags: java, algorithm, performance

I'm working on the 2-sum problem and I think my solution is quite efficient but after I ran it, the program apparently took too long. Here is my code:

```
  public int[] twoSum(int[] numbers, int target) {
        int [] original = new int[numbers.length];
        for(int i=0; i<numbers.length; i++){
            original[i] = numbers[i];
        }
        Arrays.sort(numbers);
        int [] returnArray = new int[2];
        int left = 0;
        int right = numbers.length-1;
        int found1 = 0, found2 = 0;
        int index1 = 1, index2 = numbers.length-1;
        for (;left<right;){
            if(numbers[left] + numbers[right] == target){
                found1 = numbers[left];
                found2 = numbers[right];
                break;
            }
            else if(numbers[left] + numbers[right] < target){
                left++;
            }
            else{
                right--;
            }
        }
        for(;index1<index2;){
            if(original[index1] == found1){
                returnArray[0] = index1+1;
            }
            else{
                index1 ++;
            }
            if(original[index2] == found2){
                returnArray[1] = index2+1;
            }
            else{
                index2 --;
            }

        }
        return returnArray;
    }
```

The problem states that

> You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution. The function twoSum should return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to the target, where index1 must be less than index2. Please note that your returned answers (both index1 and index2) are not zero-based.

My idea is first sort the array, then find these two elements, then two indexes. And I think it's necessary to store the original array first because the sorting changes the array. Which part of my solution is slow?

P.S. I don't use Java very often, feel free to point out my mistakes.

Thanks.

Comment: I thought the point of the 2-sum problem was to use a hash and get constant lookup.

Comment: http://www.careercup.com/question?id=15206700

Comment: Follow the solution in SGM1's link

Comment: @Keith Yes, that's one common solution. But first sorting the array is another.

Comment: @Patashu does the requirement of returning these two indexes of the elements found make any difference?

Answer (score 0):

You have two passes here. One to find the numbers and then another to remember the original indices.

If you retained the index in the first place, you avoid the second pass.

Start with an array containing the indices in order i..e { 1,2,3,4, ...}, and then sort it using a non-default comparitor:

```
sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)
```

Have that comparitor order the index using the values in the original array.

Then run your two-sum on the index and you already have the index values.

Comment: `Have that comparitor order the index using the values in the original array` I don't quite get the sorting the array with original part, could you please give me an example?

Comment: @Gnijuohz He means treat the original indices as satellite data and move them around along with the original array elements as part of sorting. You do this by sorting the indices array based on the value of the original array. Check this out for details
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898690/java-sort-array1-based-on-array2